# Bash find filter and copy - trouble with spaces

Tags: bash, find

So after a lot of searching and trying to interpret others' questions and answers to my needs, I decided to ask for myself.

I'm trying to take a directory structure full of images and place all the images (regardless of extension) in a single folder. In addition to this, I want to be able to remove images matching certain filenames in the process. I have a find command working that outputs all the filepaths for me

```
find -type f -exec file -i -- {} + | grep -i image | sed 's/\:.*//'
```

but if I try to use that to copy files, I have trouble with the spaces in the filenames.

```
cp `find -type f -exec file -i -- {} + | grep -i image | sed 's/\:.*//'` out/
```

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Presumably, you don't have file names containing newlines.  Also, given the `grep` command you're using, you don't have any files such as `windimage.o` which is an object file (not an image file) even though the file name contains 'image'.

Comment: I don't, but I'm open to suggestions for improvement in case I do encounter such a file.

Comment: What kind of filenames are you trying to remove?

Comment: depends on the situation. I'm using this as part of a script to process archive files for my nook into the proper formatting, but I'll add that part later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the results of your find command to

```
xargs -l --replace cp "{}" out/
```

Example of how this works for me on Ubuntu 10.04:

```
atomic@atomic-desktop:~/temp$ ls
img.png  img space.png
atomic@atomic-desktop:~/temp$ mkdir out
atomic@atomic-desktop:~/temp$ find -type f -exec file -i \{\} \; | grep -i image | sed 's/\:.*//' | xargs -l --replace cp -v "{}" out/
`./img.png' -> `out/img.png'
`./img space.png' -> `out/img space.png'
atomic@atomic-desktop:~/temp$ ls out
img.png  img space.png
atomic@atomic-desktop:~/temp$
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `xargs` command splits its input lines on spaces so it breaks up the file names.

Comment: I think I must be missing something.  My xargs doesn't seem to split up filenames with spaces.  I'll edit my answer with what I see.

Comment: this one worked perfectly with a bit of adjustment.

final command is 
`find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file -i | grep -i "image/" | sed 's/\:.*//' | xargs -l --replace cp \{\} out/`

although it may not be the most efficient way to deal with it. (and may have some unnecessary parts), it seems to work exactly as I expected it to

Comment: Yes, definitely 'find -print0 | xargs -0' is the safe way around this.  Though it would seem that your second xargs could still run into the same problem @JonathanLeffler brings up

Comment: used your version now, looks a lot cleaner, just changed the grep to not accidentally grab files with "image" in the name
`find -type f -exec file -i \{\} \; | grep -i image | sed 's/\:.*//' | xargs -l --replace cp -v "{}" out/`

edit: which should I use?

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat that it won't work if files have newlines in their names:

```
find . -type f -exec file -i -- {} + |
awk -vFS=: -vOFS=: '$NF ~ /image/{NF--;printf "%s\0", $0}' |
xargs -0 cp -t out/
```

(Based on answer by Jonathan Leffler and subsequent comments discussion with him and @devnull.)

Comment: Hmmm.. maybe you wanted to put the latter half in a script or something.  This is likely to confuse `-exec`.

Comment: @devnull: why? `awk` only needs to be called once, it takes its input one line at a time.

Comment: You need a `\;` before the first pipe and it should be good (actually, great)!

Comment: @devnull: Actually, I used a +; even better.

Comment: Saw that immediately after commenting.  +1

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command works well if none of the file names contain any newlines.  Within broad limits, the `grep` command works OK under the same circumstances.  The `sed` command works fine as long as there are no colons in the file names.  However, given that there are spaces in the names, the use of `$(...)` (command substitution, also indicated by back-ticks `` `...` ``) is a disaster.  Unfortunately, `xargs` isn't readily a part of the solution; it splits on spaces by default.  Because you have to run `file` and `grep` in the middle, you can't easily use the `-print0` option to (GNU) `find` and the `-0` option to (GNU) `xargs`.

In some respects, it is crude, but in many ways, it is easiest if you write an executable shell script that can be invoked by `find`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$@"
do
    if file -i -- "$file" | grep -i -q "$file:.*image"
    then cp "$file" out/
    fi
done
```

This is a little painful in that it invokes `file` and `grep` separately for each name, but it is reliable.  The `file` command is even safe if the file name contains a newline; the `grep` is probably not.

If that script is called 'copyimage.sh', then the `find` command becomes:

```
find . -type f -exec ./copyimage.sh {} +
```

And, given the way the `grep` command is written, the `copyimage.sh` file won't be copied, even though its name contains the magic word 'image'.

Comment: That grep will fail if the filename contains a regex metacharacter which is not self-matching. (i.e., `.` is ok, but `?` and `*` are not.) A better one would be `for file in "$@"; do file -i -- "$file"; done | awk -F: '$2 ~ /image/{printf "%s\0", $1}' | xargs -0 cp -t out/`

Comment: +1.  Especially for pointing out the `grep` problem (as it was originally written)!

Comment: @rici I'm not sure if piping to `awk` is a great idea.  Imagine a file named `foo:bar.jpg`

Comment: a bit of help on how I could use that one? The shell script doesn't work for me either (perhaps the [] and _ found in some filenames?)

Comment: @rici: Good point — I didn't add caveats about regex characters in file names.  I agree `awk` might be usable, but I'm not sure that what you wrote is sufficient; the word 'image' might not be the second word in the line if the file name contains colons.  This stuff is so painful.  The (GNU) extension to `cp` (and `mv`) that allows you to specify the directory via `-t target` is useful.

Comment: @devnull: yeah, that's true, it won't work with filenames containing `:`, which are legal. However, you could use $NF instead of $2, and then do a for loop to put the filename back together if needed.

Comment: If we're heavily into GNU extensions, then we could use a Perl (PCRE) regex like: `grep -P -i -e "\\Q${file}\\E:.*image"` to deal with most file names — except perhaps ones which contain the character sequence `\E`.  The `\\Q` and `\\E` bracket text to be treated verbatim.  Failing that, instead of a shell script, write a Perl script that does the analysis.  Given no newlines in file names, using the `xargs cp -t out/` idea is good. With Perl, you could arrange for the null terminated strings to be conveyed and use `xargs -0 cp -t out/`, and then even names with newlines could be handled.

Comment: @devnull & JonathanLeffler: corrected awk version which I think handles : properly in separate answer